# Extremely Simple .java Editor with Syntax highlighting

Tags: java, windows, ide, editor

Just as the title says.
I'd like to know if there is a simple Java Editor with only **syntax highlighting**.
Without auto-complete, project explorer and everything else.

As simple as windows notepad + java syntax highlighting.

Comment: Look at notepad++. also, off topic.

Comment: Not on-topic here.  Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @apnorton Thank you very much for informing. I shall ask there instead.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) if you don't like notepad++

Answer (score 1):

[Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/fr/) is as simple as it comes. It supports Java syntax highlighting out of the box (among many other languages).